# Async await Task error for load files in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await

I am trying to do an async operation in **UploadBtnExecute** method.I am working this on wpf. But it shows some error.

error are :-
error 1::-'

> Task UploadBtnExecute(object)' has the wrong return type

error 2::- '

> bool' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no accessible
> extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type
> 'bool' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
> assembly reference?)

What I have tried:

button click event to trigger a function

```
UploadBtnClick = new RelayCommands(UploadBtnExecute,UploadBtnCanExecuteUpload);

public async Task UploadBtnExecute(object param)
{
    Progress windowShow = new Progress();
    windowShow.Show();
    await UploadFiles();
    windowShow.Hide();
}

public bool UploadFiles(List<Item> selectedFiles)
{
    //do some upload code here
    return true;
}
```

Comment: `UploadFiles` needs to return `Task<bool>` for you to be able to await it above

Comment: added   return Task<bool> in upload method no change

Comment: added like     public async Task<bool> UploadBtnExecute(object param)

Comment: see my answer. `UploadFiles` should return a `Task<bool>`, as noticed by Haytam, and `UploadBtnExecute` should by `async void` (it's some eventhandler, right?)

Comment: @Pac0, i added return Task<bool> in uploadfiles.but it shows this error   'Task<bool>' is a type, which is not valid in the given context

Comment: if the function is `async Task<bool>`, you can just return `true`, C# async/await magic will turn this into a `Task<bool>` automatically. If the function is _not_  async, then you can `return Task.FromResult(true)` to properly return a `Task<bool>` type, that corresponds to your original `return true`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error 1:

An event handler must return `void`. This is this case where using `async void` instead of using `async Task` is recommended (mainly because there is no alternative, actually) for an async function that doesn't return a value.

Error 2:

Your second `UploadFiles` must return a `Task<bool>` instead of `bool` for `await` to make any sense.

Additionally, since this is the function actually doing something asynchronous, you *probably* wait it to be `async Task<bool>` and use `await` on the actual code that uploads something, but that may depend on your actual goal.

So as a summary, your snippet of code should be adapted like that:

```cs
UploadBtnClick = new RelayCommands(UploadBtnExecute,UploadBtnCanExecuteUpload);

public async void UploadBtnExecute(object param)
{
    Progress windowShow = new Progress();
    windowShow.Show();
    await UploadFiles();
    windowShow.Hide();
}

public async Task<bool> UploadFiles(List<Item> selectedFiles)
{
    // do some upload code here
    // using await ....
    return true;
}

// alternatively:
public Task<bool> UploadFiles(List<Item> selectedFiles)
{
    // do some upload code here
    return Task.FromResult(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are still getting this error, even when the code is written correctly, as I was with IAsyncOperation type functions, you may need to check that the NuGet package for System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime is installed. I thought I had created the reference for it, but it wasn't added. Installing this package fixed all my errors.
[As seen in my screenshot, go to References > Manage Nuget Packages > Browse "System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime" and make sure it is installed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdgOv.png)